# How to use the felm() command for a basic fixed effects model?

Tags: r

Panel data analysis newcomer here. The basic idea behind the regression that I'm hoping to run is that I want to find the effect of monthly average temperature on mortality by race over time. A portion of the panel data I have collected from publicly available sources looks something like this:

[image]

The data includes each year and month from 1999-2018. I also included mortality statistics (Tdeaths) for the following groups: American Indian, white, black, and asian.

This is the code that I inputted for the regression:

`fixed1 <- felm(Tdeaths ~ TEMP + Race | Year + Month, data = Race2)`

I didn't create dummy variables for each race, which I'm guessing might be part of the problem alongside the incorrect code above?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
library(lfe)
dat <- data.frame(
"race" = sample(c("white", "black", "asian"), 72, replace=TRUE),
"year" = rep(seq(2011,2016,1), each=12),
"month" = rep(c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr",
             "May", "June", "July", "Aug",
             "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"),6),
"Tdeaths" = sample(8000:1200, 72, replace=TRUE),
"temp" = sample(45:95, 72, replace=TRUE))

str(dat)
'data.frame':   72 obs. of  5 variables:
$ race   : Factor w/ 3 levels "asian","black",..: 2 2 1 2 1 3 3 1 1 3 ...
$ year   : num  2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 ...
$ month  : Factor w/ 12 levels "Apr","Aug","Dec",..: 5 4 8 1 9 7 6 2 12 11 ...
$ Tdeaths: int  2963 2361 5609 3795 3192 7662 1849 2808 2600 5847 ...
$ temp   : int  59 70 68 80 80 61 60 55 94 55 ..

 summary(est <- felm(Tdeaths ~ Temp + race | year + month, data = dat)) 

 Call:
 felm(formula = Tdeaths ~ Temp + race | year + month, data = dat) 

 Residuals:
 Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
 -3637.7 -1546.5    64.9  1309.2  3363.9 

 Coefficients:
          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
Temp         16.97      19.26   0.881    0.382
raceblack   455.74     817.24   0.558    0.579
racewhite   291.64     635.87   0.459    0.648

Residual standard error: 2156 on 52 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared(full model): 0.2309   Adjusted R-squared: -0.05017 
Multiple R-squared(proj model): 0.02333   Adjusted R-squared: -0.3335 
F-statistic(full model):0.8215 on 19 and 52 DF, p-value: 0.6728 
F-statistic(proj model): 0.414 on 3 and 52 DF, p-value: 0.7436
```

If you are getting errors, I would go back and check all your data to make sure it is properly formatted and consistent.
If you need to obtain the estimated fixed effects use, `getfe`

With your data using `lm` should work just fine.

```
lm(Tdeaths ~ Temp + race + factor(year) + factor(month), data = dat)
```

Comment: Was any of this useful to your problem?